# How to migrate branches commit history to SVN to GIT and push to GIT repository

Tags: git, svn, bitbucket

I have migrated `non standardized SVN repository` to `GIT repository` using below command.

```
git svn clone --trunk=https://svnpath/project --branches=branches/*/*/* --tags=tags/* --authors-file=authors.txt https://svnpath/project tempProject.
```

I have multiple branches created based on trunk. So I need those branches commit history as well.

Using above command, I am successfully migrating Trunk but **not able to get all the branches and its commit history**.

So, how to get all branches and its commit history after migrate svn to git?

Comment: Have you managed to do this?